# ECDH in golang - elliptic/Curve unmarshal fails

Tags: go

Unfortunaltey there is no built-in brainpool support in `go` so I'm trying to get ECDH working with the help of a fork from `keybase`.

Maybe I'm making a newbie mistake here but by code is falling at the first hurdle (i.e. `elliptic.Unmarshal` returns nil) ?

```
package main

import (
 "fmt"
 "io/ioutil"
 "log"
"encoding/pem"
"crypto/ecdsa"
"crypto/rand"
"github.com/keybase/go-crypto/brainpool"
"crypto/elliptic"
"crypto/sha256"
)

func main() {
fmt.Println("Hello")
content, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/tmp/TEST.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
fmt.Printf("File contents: %s", content)

    block, _ := pem.Decode(content)
    if block == nil || block.Type != "PUBLIC KEY" {
        log.Fatal("failed to decode PEM")
    }

x,y := elliptic.Unmarshal(brainpool.P512r1(),block.Bytes)
if x == nil {
     log.Fatal("failed to unmarshal")
}
pubb := ecdsa.PublicKey {brainpool.P512r1(),x,y}


priva, _ := ecdsa.GenerateKey(brainpool.P512r1(), rand.Reader)
b, _ := pubb.Curve.ScalarMult(pubb.X, pubb.Y, priva.D.Bytes())

shared1 := sha256.Sum256(b.Bytes())

fmt.Printf("\nShared key %x\n",  shared1)
```

Update to show the test key:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGbMBQGByqGSM49AgEGCSskAwMCCAEBDQOBggAEM/zOLT7nMN374k902oTRZXnG
97DPzvqi8QQJaKXcq1BSrU/sNeUhOi6Y+hBcr7ZE+WZDYNoQkaMNrdhF+3x1XGx7
BTBFL3U1w2ENmkIPiDa2o0Q/wpSOLo/RFabdK5Q3/yvq0hoSdXlpKozE7UTre5cU
bJcUzjXvs9KDLEq54Fs=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: Any chance you could post a key (obviously not a sensitive one)?  I'm not sure it is necessary to import the brainpool library just to get a curve.

Comment: @PassKit Updated with contents of `/tmp/TEST.pem` which is a throw-away test key not being used for anything other than this test code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to unmarshal the raw ASN.1 message, not the public key part.  You should first unmarshal the ASN.1 block, then unmarshal the EC data.

I was wrong in my comment, Go doesn't support the Brainpool functions. So I borrowed some code from their X509 package to build a custom parser for the 6 curves in the Brainpool package.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/i-Zd4mTugjU

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "crypto/elliptic"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "crypto/x509/pkix"
    "encoding/asn1"
    "encoding/pem"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/big"

    "github.com/keybase/go-crypto/brainpool"
)

const ecKey = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGbMBQGByqGSM49AgEGCSskAwMCCAEBDQOBggAEM/zOLT7nMN374k902oTRZXnG
97DPzvqi8QQJaKXcq1BSrU/sNeUhOi6Y+hBcr7ZE+WZDYNoQkaMNrdhF+3x1XGx7
BTBFL3U1w2ENmkIPiDa2o0Q/wpSOLo/RFabdK5Q3/yvq0hoSdXlpKozE7UTre5cU
bJcUzjXvs9KDLEq54Fs=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`

func main() {
    block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(ecKey))
    if block == nil || block.Type != "PUBLIC KEY" {
        log.Fatal("failed to decode PEM")
    }

    pub, err := parseBrainpoolPKIXPublicKey(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to parse key: %v", err)
    }

    pubb := ecdsa.PublicKey{Curve: brainpool.P512r1(), X: pub.X, Y: pub.Y}
    priva, _ := ecdsa.GenerateKey(brainpool.P512r1(), rand.Reader)
    b, _ := pubb.Curve.ScalarMult(pubb.X, pubb.Y, priva.D.Bytes())

    shared1 := sha256.Sum256(b.Bytes())

    fmt.Printf("\nShared key %x\n", shared1)
}

type publicKeyInfo struct {
    Raw       asn1.RawContent
    Algorithm pkix.AlgorithmIdentifier
    PublicKey asn1.BitString
}

type pkcs1PublicKey struct {
    N *big.Int
    E int
}

var (
    oidNamedCurveBrainpoolP256r1 = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 3, 36, 3, 3, 2, 8, 1, 1, 7}
    oidNamedCurveBrainpoolP256t1 = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 3, 36, 3, 3, 2, 8, 1, 1, 8}
    oidNamedCurveBrainpoolP384r1 = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 3, 36, 3, 3, 2, 8, 1, 1, 11}
    oidNamedCurveBrainpoolP384t1 = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 3, 36, 3, 3, 2, 8, 1, 1, 12}
    oidNamedCurveBrainpoolP512r1 = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 3, 36, 3, 3, 2, 8, 1, 1, 13}
    oidNamedCurveBrainpoolP512t1 = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 3, 36, 3, 3, 2, 8, 1, 1, 14}
)

func parseBrainpoolPKIXPublicKey(derBytes []byte) (pub *ecdsa.PublicKey, err error) {
    var pki publicKeyInfo
    if rest, err := asn1.Unmarshal(derBytes, &pki); err != nil {
        if _, err := asn1.Unmarshal(derBytes, &pkcs1PublicKey{}); err == nil {
            return nil, errors.New("failed to parse public key")
        }
        return nil, err
    } else if len(rest) != 0 {
        return nil, errors.New("trailing data after ASN.1 of public-key")
    }
    if !pki.Algorithm.Algorithm.Equal(asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 2, 840, 10045, 2, 1}) {
        return nil, errors.New("not an ECDSA public key")
    }
    return parseBrainpoolPublicKey(&pki)
}

func parseBrainpoolPublicKey(keyData *publicKeyInfo) (*ecdsa.PublicKey, error) {
    asn1Data := keyData.PublicKey.RightAlign()
    paramsData := keyData.Algorithm.Parameters.FullBytes
    namedCurveOID := new(asn1.ObjectIdentifier)
    rest, err := asn1.Unmarshal(paramsData, namedCurveOID)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("failed to parse ECDSA parameters as named curve")
    }
    if len(rest) != 0 {
        return nil, errors.New("trailing data after ECDSA parameters")
    }
    namedCurve := namedCurveFromOID(*namedCurveOID)
    if namedCurve == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("unsupported elliptic curve")
    }
    x, y := elliptic.Unmarshal(namedCurve, asn1Data)
    if x == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("failed to unmarshal elliptic curve point")
    }
    pub := &ecdsa.PublicKey{
        Curve: namedCurve,
        X:     x,
        Y:     y,
    }
    return pub, nil
}

func namedCurveFromOID(oid asn1.ObjectIdentifier) elliptic.Curve {
    switch {
    case oid.Equal(oidNamedCurveBrainpoolP256r1):
        return brainpool.P256r1()
    case oid.Equal(oidNamedCurveBrainpoolP256t1):
        return brainpool.P256t1()
    case oid.Equal(oidNamedCurveBrainpoolP384r1):
        return brainpool.P384r1()
    case oid.Equal(oidNamedCurveBrainpoolP384t1):
        return brainpool.P384t1()
    case oid.Equal(oidNamedCurveBrainpoolP512r1):
        return brainpool.P512r1()
    case oid.Equal(oidNamedCurveBrainpoolP512t1):
        return brainpool.P512t1()
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me get to the bottom of this conundrum !  I did experiment yesterday with various other parts of core `go` but never got anywhere, I guess because like you I thought a curve was readable by anything.  But you've rightly ultimately identified that you need to drop down to a slightly lower level.